# Kubernetes job for creating couchbase collections dynamically

Tags: kubernetes, couchbase

I am looking for approach how to create collections in existing scope of couchbase dynamically. Requirement is it should be periodic and should NOT be done via spring application  but via some external kubernetes job. Any such reference implementation would be available for kubernetes job which will create collections dynamically in couchbase. Frequency of this job will be less may be every few months.

Comment: You can create a K8s job that runs a rest API to create those, or just use our Operator to create Buckets/Scopes/Collections 
for example: https://docs-staging.couchbase.com/operator/current/resource/couchbasecollection.html

Comment: As @RoiKatz mentioned you can create K8 jobs to create the couchbase colletion with the help of API's . If you want jobs to be periodic then use the cron jobs and schedule them as per requirement.

Comment: Updated link from @RoiKatz 's message:  https://docs.couchbase.com/operator/current/resource/couchbasecollection.html